# How to obtain ref of Stack

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

[Stack](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/stack) doesn't expose either componentRef or ref property. How can we obtain react ref to it?
In my scenario, I want to use it with [useResponsiveMode](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/1817a5e193448ab6f456e3bd9445e537fd64348c/packages/react/src/utilities/hooks/useResponsiveMode.tsx#L12).

A workaround is to wrap Stack with a parent div.

Comment: I have the same UC. Currently there is just one way for implementation with `parent div`. How about to open a feature request on their GitHub ?https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/labels/Component%3A%20Stack